# Child elevation of ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-elevation

I have a problem with the class ExpandableListView Android. I use the API 10 and AppCompat Theme, to develop an application. I have implemented a ExpandableListView, but I would like to expand when a group has an elevation effect on their children. Any idea? Thanks for advance!!